# how does jwplayer initialize when embedded in sitefinity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jwplayer, sitefinity

We are using a Sitefinity portal and have the jwplayer on one of our pages. When I edit the page, all I see in the HTML code is a DIV with an ID for the video player. I do not see any reference to the javascript code. However, when I load the page, I see the setup() function and the script reference to the .js file.

I am trying to figure out where and at what point the setup() and reference to the .js code is loaded into the page.

We are experiencing a problem where the Sitefinity portal is loading over https and the media content (a remotely hosted .mp4 file) is loading over http. Because of the mixed https/http content this will not load on the page.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!
Bob

Comment: Do you have an example of where you have set this up?

Comment: Can you get to this link? It is a screen capture of the code that is generated in the ContentBlock within Sitefinity.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIeQ61b2QaMm4xV2NWX3g4NWs

Comment: However, this is all I see when I edit the content block

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ZIeQ61b2QaUW54Wlc0d0lYcFU

Comment: Hm, does sitefinity allow for JavaScript to be posted? It looks like it is stripping it out.

Comment: I agree. What is interesting is that the second image I shared is the content which is edit-able. The first image I shared is what gets rendered on the page after publishing. If I load the page via HTTP it works fine but over HTTPS the media file will not load (because of the mixed mode content). Do you think there could be server side code that is generating the JS code? I am not too familiar with JWPlayer so I'm not sure how it is normally initialized, although I have spent a good portion of the day researching online. Thanks for taking the time to help with this.

Comment: I think that the javascript is stripped. You could load the javascript for JwPlayer in a separate file and inject it on the Page_Load or just reference it in one of your masterpages. Would that work?

Comment: That's a good point. It is still a mystery why I cannot see the JS code prior from the Sitefinity backend. When I look at the page source on the website, I can see the JS code. I'll give this a try but I am concerned that I may end up with two instances of the code on the page. Didn't realize changing an http to https would be so involved!!! :)

Comment: Can I see a link to where it is running on the public facing site?

Comment: Thanks Ethan. Can you send me an e-mail to rbolton240@gmail.com, and I'll create an account for you to get to it. The website that it is running on requires secure access.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the js in the first place? You cannot edit  tags in a Content Block.

As an alternative you can add a Javascript widget to the page ("Scripts and Styles" section). You won't have it double once you save the Content Block with the js stripped.

Comment: The person that set this up is no longer with the company... trying to do some detective work to figure out how it works. Thanks.